# Swift Stuck with restoring purchases?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

i have been following online tutorials for IAP's in swift. I have payments working, aswell as the delivery of products. The final hurdle i am stuck on is restoring purchases. I am confused how this is done and if i am doing this correctly.

Generic IAP Helper Class with methods 
Line 62 and 126 show the restore purchase methods
http://pastebin.com/f61w0zU8

Method i am using to call restore of purchases, while it shows the products i have purchased in the console log, it is not updating the UI as if the item was purchased. (When an item is purchased it shows a button in the storyboard)

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
reload()

 RageProducts.store.restorePurchases()
  }
```

I followed the tutorial, but do not understand how to get this working, and why it is not working, and why transaction observer is not called here, All help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown anything that would update the UI once purchases are restored. Why would you expect the button corresponding to a purchase to appear?

Comment: So when a purchase is succesful it sends a ns notification which when received shows the elements of the ui. My thoughts were the restore purchase case also utilised this ns notification and thus products should be given like a purchase

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more information. That pastebin link has expired or been removed so you're talking about a lot of behavior no one else can see. StoreKit doesn't have a `restorePurchases` method or send notifications so there's no way to know what your store helper does, if you should expect a notification, and if so if you are handling the data associated with that notification correctly.